# Why are there hyphens and underscores in Base64 encoded data from the "cryptography" Python package?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, base64

I am using the Python [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) package to generate encryption data. I can generate an encryption token no problem, like this:

```
b'gAAAAABl4-BVigmotWHPCxDKkGT-weDwK0DcdiHyW9U8rthD2B61dTCQw1Gnt7JcyCvWmxW2INNws_hbK1ecReEaqJKEaXJCZg=='
```

I can then use that to successfully decrypt my data using that same cryptography package.

I want to decrypt my data using a different package (a JavaScript package), so I need to extract the IV and cipher text from that token. However, I'm running into issues, since Base64 tokens like that are not supposed to contain hyphens nor underscores. By strictly following the [fernet spec](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md), the IV should be this:

```
b'igmotWHPCxDKkGT-weDwKw=='
```

However, when I put that into my JavaScript package, it's rejected, since Base64 encoded data cannot have hyphens. Are the hyphens and underscores supposed to be replaced with something else?

Notes:

- According to the [fernet spec](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md#token-format), the token should have `57 + 16x` bytes (`456 + 128x bits`), so 73 bytes, 89 bytes, etc. According to `len(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(token))` (where `token` stores the token above), my token has 73 bytes, so that appears to be fine.
- To get the IV above, I am using `urlsafe_b64encode(urlsafe_b64decode(token)[9:25])`. Using the `urlsafe` version was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55106160/10368970). I was using `b64edecode()`, but I would sometimes (but not always) get the error `binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (93) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4`.

Comment: Show the code used to generate the token. Make a [mcve]

Comment: Please post your most recent JavaScript code and in particular specify the JavaScript crypto library used. It looks like you want to do the Fernet decryption manually. Then be aware that Fernet is an *authenticated* encryption and you have to do the authentication as well (otherwise you lose the security associated with the authentication). There are Fernet packages for JavaScript/NodeJS that you could (or should) use, e.g. [fernet.js](https://jsfiddle.net/cep132s4/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hyphens and underscores in your Base64 encoded data from the `cryptography` Python package are a result of URL-safe Base64 encoding. This encoding scheme replaces `+` and `/` characters with `-` and `_`, respectively, to make the data more suitable for use in URLs and filenames.

To extract the IV and ciphertext from the token for use in a different package (such as a JavaScript encryption library), you need to decode the Base64 data and then replace the hyphens and underscores back to `+` and `/` before decoding it in JavaScript.

1. Python: Use the `urlsafe_b64decode` function to decode the Base64 encoded token and extract the IV:

```py
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet, InvalidToken

token = b'your_token_here'
fernet = Fernet('your_key_here')
try:
    iv = token[:16]  # The first 16 bytes of the token are the IV
    ciphertext = token[16:]  # The rest is the ciphertext
    decrypted_data = fernet.decrypt(token)
except InvalidToken:
    print("Invalid token")
```

1. JavaScript: Replace the hyphens and underscores back to + and / in the IV before decoding it using atob:

```js
let token = 'your_token_here';
let base64IV = token.slice(9, 25).replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
let iv = new Uint8Array(Array.prototype.map.call(atob(base64IV), c => c.charCodeAt(0)));
```

This code snippet first extracts the IV portion from the token, replaces the URL-safe characters, and then decodes the Base64 string into a Uint8Array, which can be used as the IV for decryption in your JavaScript encryption library.

Documentations:

[cryptography](https://cryptography.io)

[Fernet tokens](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/)

Comment: Or just use `base64.b64encode()` which uses + and / to begin with.

Comment: yes you're right @MarkTolonen

Comment: @MarkTolonen You mean modify the Fernet source code?

Comment: @nocomment No, I mean `iv = base64.b64encode(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(token)[9:25])` -> `b'igmotWHPCxDKkGT+weDwKw=='` and then patching it in Javascript as this code is doing is not needed.  But I don't know exactly what the javascript package needs.  This is just more simple than this answer.

Comment: Neither your [Python code](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/XCR) with `gAAAAABl4-BVigmo` nor your [JavaScript code](https://jsfiddle.net/cep132s4/1/) with `+BVigmotWHPCxDKk` returns the correct IV (`igmotWHPCxDKkGT+weDwKw==`)! In the Python code, the Base64url decoding is missing when determining the IV and the inner structure of the token is not taken into account. In the JavaScript code, although the token is extracted based on the inner structure of the *raw* token, it is extracted *before* the Base64url decoding.